# Apache POI - change shape order in pptx

Tags: java, apache-poi

I can't seem to find the following feature in the POI documentation or class descriptions:

`XSLFShape` sometimes overlap on a slide. In Powerpoint, you can move the order to change which shape shows at the top. Is this possible with Apache POI?

Comment: The PPTX file is just a zip of xml files. Have you tried saving a before and after of changing the z-order of a shape to see how this is represented in the file structure? This might give you a hint on how to accomplish this with POI. The shape belongs to a container. Did you try removing and readding the shape to the container?

Answer (score 0):

There is ugly but working solutions to bring shapes on front:

```java
   static void bringShapesOnFront(XSLFSlide slide, Predicate<XSLFShape> moveOnFront) {
        try {
            Method m = XSLFSheet.class.getDeclaredMethod("getSpTree");
            m.setAccessible(true);

            List<XSLFShape> shapes = slide.getShapes().stream()
                    .filter(moveOnFront)
                    .collect(toList());

            shapes.forEach(s -> {
                try {
                    if (s instanceof XSLFPictureShape) {
                        ((CTGroupShapeImpl) m.invoke(slide)).addNewPic().set(s.getXmlObject().copy());
                    } else {
                        ((CTGroupShapeImpl) m.invoke(slide)).addNewSp().set(s.getXmlObject().copy());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.info(String.format("Couldn't invoke method for copy shape cause: %s", e));
                }
            });
            shapes.stream()
                    .filter(s -> !(s instanceof XSLFGroupShape) && !(s instanceof XSLFPictureShape))
                    .forEach(slide::removeShape);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(String.format("Couldn't copy shape cause: %s", e));
        }
    }
```